# Setting webpage background image while using Zurb Foundation?

Tags: css, background-image, zurb-foundation

I use the following [css3 code to make a background image a near perfect 100%](http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/) of the browser window:

```
html { 
    background: url(images/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

However, I also use the Zurb Foundation 3 css framework and it automatically makes the `body` element have a white background... so the above background image is hidden. Obviously I can override that, but it makes me think I need to handle backgrounds like the above in a special way with Foundation. Is that true? Or do I need to also have this:

```
body {
  background: transparent !important;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I use Foundation 5 but not with images I use gradients instead but the same should apply if you wanted to use an image . . .

The Banner

```
<div id="banner">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="small-12 columns">Some Content Here</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The CSS - NOTE THE WIDTH AND Z-INDEX this will mean that the background will take up 100% of the page width and the z-index will put it below any of foundations other elements 
the best way to apply this is either on the page or on a stylesheet that is loaded AFTER foundation.min.css otherwise it will not override the presets of foundation.

```
#banner{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    min-height:100%;
    z-index:-999;
    background: url(images/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
    margin:0;padding:0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

EDIT NOTE: Sorry, I thought the !important property item you placed there was the Zurb code. Either way I will leave my answer for what it is worth.

I am not familiar with Zurb Foundation 3, but typically if a developer uses the !important property it is because they deem it as vital to the rest of the code and do not want it overwritten. However, we are talking about a background, which does not inherit, therefore, I do not see how the background property on the body tag could actually ever be 'vital', as in, it will break the layout if you remove it.

I was thinking about z-index for the body and how a developer might want to put certain items behind the body, although I have never seen this and don't know why you would want to do this. Further, I believe that negative z-index is supposed to place something behind the body, however, we don't see this happen. See my various fiddles with trying to hide a div behind the body.

http://jsfiddle.net/W9ckz/1/ http://jsfiddle.net/W9ckz/2/ http://jsfiddle.net/W9ckz/3/ http://jsfiddle.net/W9ckz/4/

So unless you can think of another way that overriding the background on the body might break the layout and can prove that it is a threat to that effect (unlike the z-index thing I thought of) then I would say go for it. Worst that happens is that you have to undo it.

```
I think you can remove the body background
property altogether without side effect.
```

Answer (score 0):

I would apply your `html`'s style to `body`  instead. The outcome will be the same and you will be overriding Foundation's default white background.

Comment: this would actually not be the same. Sometimes the `body` has a lower `height` than the browser window.